# PC slow when one ssd is at 100% usage despite having two ssds

Tags: ssd, performance, storage

When I’m downloading something, or doing anything that makes my C drive get to 100% usage my system slows down. I could understand that happening if I had one ssd but I have two, and both have decent storage left.

C Drive: 31 gb free of 500 gb

Other drive: 22.5 gb used of 2 tb

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145990/discussion-on-question-by-cabbage-pc-slow-when-one-ssd-is-at-100-usage-despite); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.